# Making a parallelogram shape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android graphics and shapes so I'm a little confused. How can I make a Parallelogram shape in Android XML? I tried searching over the web but I couldn't find anything specific.
I saw that this can be done in code, but as I'm trying to set this as a background of a layout it's gonna be quite difficult for me to manage it if I do it in code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to set it as layout background then you can create an image of parallelogram and use that...

Comment: I'm running our of options...I think that's what I'll have to end up doing

Comment: One google search for "android xml parallelogram" turned this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397744/programmatically-create-parallelogram-drawable-in-android

Comment: @Shanzid whats wrong with View.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) ?

Comment: sometimes the image gets distorted, that's why I'm not really looking into an image for a background

Comment: @Shanzid see this https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable

Answer (score 3):

as simple as SVG coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="50">

    <path android:fillColor="#6653cfa5"
        android:pathData="M 200 0 L 20 0 L 0 50 L 180 50 L 200 0" />

</vector>
```